# How do I set an environment variable in an EKS worker node (for CNI configuration)?

Tags: amazon-web-services

According to [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/cni-env-vars.html) article, I can set configuration variables for the CNI plugin (which allows worker node EC2 instances to connect to the EKS hub) through an environment variable.  I want to set WARM_IP_TARGET to 2.

When I made my auto scaling group for worker nodes I used the AMI that amazon suggests that already has the plugin.  Am I expected to create my own AMI with a preset environment variable and then recreate the autoscaling group? Where do I even set the environment variables?

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer in this EKS workshop, where there's an example of 'Configure Custom networking' via AWS_VPC_K8S_CNI_CUSTOM_NETWORK_CFG:

https://eksworkshop.com/beginner/160_advanced-networking/secondary_cidr/configure-cni/

Here's the excerpt from the above link:

> Edit aws-node configmap and add AWS_VPC_K8S_CNI_CUSTOM_NETWORK_CFG
>   environment variable to the node container spec and set it to true
>
> Note: You only need to set one environment variable in the CNI
>   daemonset configuration:
>
> `kubectl set env ds aws-node -n kube-system AWS_VPC_K8S_CNI_CUSTOM_NETWORK_CFG=true`
>
> `kubectl describe daemonset aws-node -n kube-system | grep -A5 Environment`
>
> ```
> Environment:
>   AWS_VPC_K8S_CNI_LOGLEVEL:     DEBUG
>   AWS_VPC_K8S_CNI_CUSTOM_NETWORK_CFG: true
>   MY_NODE_NAME:                     (v1:spec.nodeName) ...
> ```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/24750077)

Comment: Sure @ArunPratap, I just added it.